# template variables not parsing inside javascript

Tags: javascript, variable

I have some javascript in a template and when I try to use template variables inside the  ...  tags, the template variables are not parsing.

All other template vars on the page are parsing as expected.

I also have $config['protect_javascript'] set to "n"

**Code in template:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#{pricing_button}{pricing_button_attr_id}{/pricing_button}').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked it!');
    alert('{ga_event}');
});
</script>
```

**The rendered page results:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#{pricing_button}{pricing_button_attr_id}{/pricing_button}').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked it!');
    alert('{ga_event}');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I assume {pricing_button} is wrapped in {exp:channel:entries} or something and renders outside of the JS tags? Try setting a var first and not have the tag curlies in the JQuery: var target = '#{pricing_button}{pricing_button_attr_id}{/pricing_button}'; $(target).on ... etc.

Comment: That was it.  Sigh.  I had it outside the {exp:channel:entries} block.  Thank you :)